# Woocommerce order area stop working after website migration

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, version-control

I am working on to the website, after making transfer into another server the woocommmerce order area not working but rest of website works properly.

Can anyone who get this issue. Please help me to find the issue.

Wordpress version:4.8.8
PHP version:7.4
Woocommerce version: 2.5.5
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried changing theme, and de-activate plugins one by one ? which others plugins are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

You check first is that your orders are available in database or not. If Order lists data available in your database then you should check you site using your debugging tools.